# Nginx valid referrers for all except specific route

Tags: nginx

I’m using valid referrers in nginx to block access to an api system unless it comes from allowed domains, this basic idea:

```
location / {
            valid_referers example.com example2.com;
            if ($invalid_referer = ''){
                    return 403;
            }
           
    }
```

I need to be able to allow any referrer to urls ending in /external

So example.com/external/test1 example.com/external/test2

These would be valid to allow any referrer but I’m not sure how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate location block

```
location / {
        valid_referers example.com example2.com;
        if ($invalid_referer = ''){
                return 403;
        }
       
}
location /external {
 # your logic
       
}
```

Comment: Would that new block need to come before the first one? Otherwise it’s going to pick up the original block first right? Also would it need to have regex after /external ? Just asking because wouldn’t this only work if the url was exact /external ?

Comment: It doesn't need to regex. The exact URL match is using `=`. eg. `location = /external {}` The order of location blocks doesn't matter in your case. More on that https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms